# Starting WCF Client in IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, iis, wcf-client

It is possible to have WCF Client that connects persistantly using duplex over net.tcp (netTcpBinding) from IIS?

i.e. the normal way would be to host it in a console app or as a windows service, my question is, could one use a shared hosting type of environment to run a WCF Client application.

i.e. the application isn't ever accessible from the outside, the application just connects to another service and consumes a remote WCF service over the internet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the ASP.NET app is the client, you could try loading the WCF Client into an Application or Session variable.

I've done something slightly similar with a System Timer and it worked a treat.